# Sorting nested lists by specific logic - Python

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, nested-lists

A nested list,

```
A = [[2, 0], [1, 0], [4, 3], [3, 2], [5, 1]]
```

I am trying to sort it based on the `1st` element in ascending order, i.e

```
result_A = [[2, 0], [1, 0], [5, 1], [3, 2], [4, 3]]
```

When the `1st` element is common in any of the nested lists, I am trying to sort it based on the `0th` element. So,

```
required_A = [[1, 0], [2, 0], [5, 1], [3, 2], [4, 3]]
```

This is my code so far:

```
required_A = sorted(A, key=itemgetter(1))
```

I am able to sort it based on the `1st` element, but am clueless how to sort it again on the `0th` element without the remaining order getting messed up. Thanks!

Comment: or just `sorted(A, key=lambda x: x[::-1])`

Answer (score 1):

This shows how to fix your [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) code.

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(A, key=itemgetter(1, 0))
[[1, 0], [2, 0], [5, 1], [3, 2], [4, 3]]
```

When you pass multiple arguments to `itemgetter`, it returns a function that can be used to construct a tuple from a given sequence with values from the respective indices that were provided as arguments to `itemgetter`.

Tuples, like all sequences, can be compared [lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) in Python. That means they will be compared from left-to-right, index by index, until one sequence overtakes the other. It also means that tuples make excellent keys for your sort.

Answer (score 1):

Provided we have items in individual sublists in the reversed order, we can sort the whole list directly. So let's inform the `sorted` function that we want to consider reversed sublists:

```
sorted(A, key=lambda x: list(reversed(x))
```

Comment: You should really explain how your answer works :-)

Comment: Added a bit of explanation.